# Proving nearest integer function identity

Tags: modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

While trying to express the nearest integer function in terms of the modulo or floor function to make some lunar ephemeris equations more compact, I noticed (using GeoGebra) that
$$\lfloor x\rceil=1+\lfloor x-1/2\rfloor$$
Is it true? If so, how would one prove it?

Comment: You could prove it with casework on whether $\{x\}<\frac{1}{2}$ or $\{x\}\geq \frac{1}{2}$. Where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: @OrdpT Regarding having an equivalent compact equation, note that $1 + \left\lfloor x - \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor (x + 1) - \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor x + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four cases.  (There may be fewer cases; I've made no attempt to determine if these cases can be handled together.)

- $x$ is an integer.  Then $1+\lfloor x-1/2 \rfloor = 1 + (x-1) = x$, as expected.
- $x$ is one-half more than an integer, $n$.  Then $1 + \lfloor (n+1/2) - 1/2 \rfloor = 1 + \lfloor n \rfloor = n+1$, which may or not be the behaviour you expect.
- $n$ is an integer and $x \in (n,n+1/2)$.  Then \begin{align*}
  n &< x < n+1/2  \\
  n - 1/2 &< x -1/2 < n  \\
  \lfloor n - 1/2 \rfloor &\leq \lfloor x -1/2 \rfloor < \lfloor n \rfloor \\
  n-1 &\leq \lfloor x -1/2 \rfloor < n \\
  1 + (n-1) &\leq 1 + \lfloor x -1/2 \rfloor < 1 + n \\
  n &\leq 1 + \lfloor x -1/2 \rfloor < n + 1 \text{,}
  \end{align*}
  and since the expression in the middle is an integer, it must be $n$, as expected.
- A similar argument for integer $n$ and $x \in (n-1/2, n)$: \begin{align*}
  n - 1/2 &< x < n  \\
  n - 1 &< x - 1/2 < n - 1/2  \\
  \lfloor n - 1 \rfloor &\leq \lfloor x -1/2 \rfloor \leq \lfloor n - 1/2 \rfloor \\
  n-1 &\leq \lfloor x -1/2 \rfloor \leq n-1 \\
  1 + (n-1) &\leq 1 + \lfloor x -1/2 \rfloor \leq 1 + (n-1) \\
  n &\leq 1 + \lfloor x -1/2 \rfloor \leq n \text{,}
  \end{align*}
  so we obtain $n$, as expected.